# Разные аватарки отображаются в расширенном и кратком режимах

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, дизайн

По всей видимости, у пользователя [@cy6erGn0m](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/335/cy6ergn0m) используется Identicon в качестве аватара. Тем не менее, [в данном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/9113/%D0%A5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-1024-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8) в качестве аватарки показывается фотография с Gravatar.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Которая благополучно меняется на Identicon в развернутом режиме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это ожидаемое поведение? Не нашел соответствующего пункта в настройках.

Comment: Угу, выглядит как баг.

Comment: По-прежнему воспроизводится. Наверное, результат миграции.